# I am getting an error on React Native when pushing value to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am making an app with react native and firebase but I am having problem with error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.desativado.push')` when I click **+** button.

[image]

Complete code -> https://pastebin.com/a9HmB89G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing `state = {desativados: []};` which has an 's' at the end?

Because from the code `state = {desativado: ""};`, `desativado`(without s at the end) is a string, there is no push method for it.

```
state = {itens: "", novositens: [], desativados: []}; // consolidate in one line to avoid overridden 

this.setState({
    desativados: this.state.desativados.concat(chave), // push to desativados instead of desativado
    bagulho: this.state.novositens.concat(nome)
})
```

**Better to get current state provided by setState**

```
this.setState((state) => {
  return {
    desativados: state.desativados.concat(chave),
    bagulho: state.novositens.concat(nome)
});
```

Comment: Still returning an error, https://imgur.com/a/pBCTuRJ

Full code with changes: https://pastebin.com/0XtEUkYE

Comment: I updated the answer, try to use `concat()`, `push()` will only return the new length of the data which mutate the type of `desativados` and `novositens` from array to int while `concat()` will return a new array with latest item included

Comment: ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.novositens.concat')```

Comment: Can you try to consolidate the state in one line ` state = {itens: "", novositens: [], desativados: []};` instead of 3 lines.  state is overridden. Updated my answer as well

Comment: You literally saved my life, this app is a mothers day gift for my mom for tomorrow!! Thank you!

Comment: @Gabriellcreiss keep on going and hope your mother like it